# Calculating the number of days between two dates as number

Tags: qgis, expression

For some expression in QGIS I need to get the number of days between two dates as numeric value.

If I substract two dates I get an interval back:

```
to_date('2019-12-31') - to_date('2019-01-01')
```

gives

```
<interval: 364 days>
```

I get the same return type from the `age()` function.

Is there a straightforward approach to get the number of days as numeric value?

I am *not* looking for solutions that involve converting to epoch and doing my own math nor for solutions that rely on string parsing. I am looking for an built-in approach that I might be overlooking.

Comment: see > https://nathanw.net/2012/06/30/better-date-and-time-support-in-qgis-expressions-and-styles/

Comment: Nice! I did not expect the day() function to work on intervals due to its name. Thanks! Do you want to add it as answer? Otherwise I will do so.

Comment: I cannot get the following to work:

exp = QgsExpression(to_date(mostRecent) - to_date(secondNewest))

Produces: "NameError: name 'to_date' is not defined" 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I never used QgsExpression but I guess you need to pass a string with the expression in it to it. This is better asked in a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions to extract temporal "parts" `year()`, `month()`, `week()`, `day()`, `hour()`, `minute()` and `second()` have a secondary function on intervals where they actually calculate the number of years, months, weeks and so on.

For example

```
day(
  to_date('2019-12-31') - to_date('2019-01-01')
)
```

returns

```
364
```

as there are that many days in that time interval.

Thanks to @Mapperz for the link.