# Calculate date difference (days) with expressions (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, expression, date, datetime

I would like to calculate the number of days between two dates. The first date is written in attribute table [YYYY-MM-DD] (creation date) and the second is today [now()]. The goal is, to get the age of every feature. 
I need it as QGIS expression to create a virtual field.

```
date1 (attribute in table) - now() = age (as virt. field)
```

Comment: Have you consulted the tooltips in the field calculator? If so, what is the exact problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332392/calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-as-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the duration between the two dates using the `age` function. Since it returns a timespan, you can then extract the number of days from it.

```
day(age(now(),"creation_date"))
```